# How can I move a view to see a UITextField when the keyboard is present, when using UICollectionViewFlowLayout

Tags: ipad, keyboard, xamarin.ios, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a method to move a CollectionView if two text fields inside it are obscured by the frame of the iPad keyboard:

```
    private void OnKeyboardNotification(NSNotification notification)
    {
        var activeTextField = FindFirstResponder(CollectionView);

        NSDictionary userInfo = notification.UserInfo;
        CGSize keyboardSize = ((NSValue)userInfo[UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey]).RectangleFValue.Size;

        var contentInset = new UIEdgeInsets(0, 0, keyboardSize.Height, 0);
        CollectionView.ContentInset = contentInset;
        CollectionView.ScrollIndicatorInsets = contentInset;

        CGRect oldRect = CollectionView.Frame;
        CGRect aRect = new CGRect(oldRect.X, oldRect.Y, oldRect.Width,
                                  oldRect.Height -= keyboardSize.Height);
        if (!aRect.Contains(activeTextField.Frame.Location))
        {
            CGPoint scrollPoint = new CGPoint(0, activeTextField.Frame.Location.Y - (keyboardSize.Height - 15));
            CollectionView.SetContentOffset(scrollPoint, true);
        }
    }
```

I don't believe the code is working as intended. It's complicated by the fact that I have a custom layout defined in a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout. The layout allows me to have cells scrolling vertically which snap into focus.

Every time I call `OnKeyboardNotification`, `override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[]` is called afterwards in the custom layout. I thought this might be cancelling out the effect of the method, but if that's the case, then how can I change when `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[]` is called?

```
    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(CGRect rect)
    {
        var array = base.LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect(rect);
        var visibleRect = new CGRect(CollectionView.ContentOffset, CollectionView.Bounds.Size);

        foreach (var attributes in array)
        {
            if (attributes.Frame.IntersectsWith(rect))
            {
                float distance = (float)(visibleRect.GetMidX() - attributes.Center.X);
                float normalizedDistance = distance / ACTIVE_DISTANCE;
                if (Math.Abs(distance) < ACTIVE_DISTANCE)
                {
                    float zoom = 1 + ZOOM_FACTOR * (1 - Math.Abs(normalizedDistance));
                    attributes.Transform3D = CATransform3D.MakeScale(zoom, zoom, 1.0f);
                    attributes.ZIndex = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return array;
    }
```

Edit:

Here is an example of the problem.

I have two fields

[image]

and here, when 'edit mode' is entered, the keyboard hides the age field.

[image]

Comment: I can not get you problem clearly, could you post some screen shot to show the problem?

Comment: Of course, please see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you use the sample from Xamarin Samples.

UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes will be invoked every time you change the size of your UICollectionView.

I suggest you changing the location of your view instead of changing size in your OnKeyboardNotification method:

```
    CGRect oldRect = CollectionView.Frame;
    CGRect aRect = new CGRect(oldRect.X, oldRect.Y  - keyboardSize.Height, oldRect.Width,oldRect.Height);
```

Hope it can solve your problem, I'm midnight right now, if it can not work, leave some message, I will check latter when tomorrow morning.

Edit -----------------------------------------------------------------

I change some code in the Sample you using to make the effect.

At first, I choose the LineLayout in AppDelegate.cs, like this:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        //Don't change anything

//            simpleCollectionViewController = new SimpleCollectionViewController (flowLayout);
        simpleCollectionViewController = new SimpleCollectionViewController (lineLayout);
//            simpleCollectionViewController = new SimpleCollectionViewController (circleLayout);

        simpleCollectionViewController.CollectionView.ContentInset = new UIEdgeInsets (50, 0, 0, 0);

        window.RootViewController = simpleCollectionViewController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
```

And then, I add a static property to LineLayout.cs, like this:

```
public class LineLayout : UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    private static bool flagForLayout = true;
    public static bool FlagForLayout {
        get {
            return flagForLayout;
        }
        set {
            flagForLayout = value;
        }
    }

    public const float ITEM_SIZE = 200.0f;
    public const int ACTIVE_DISTANCE = 200;
    public const float ZOOM_FACTOR = 0.3f;

    public LineLayout ()
    {
        //Don't change anything
    }

    public override bool ShouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange (CGRect newBounds)
    {
        return flagForLayout;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes[] LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect (CGRect rect)
    {
        //Don't change anything
    }

    public override CGPoint TargetContentOffset (CGPoint proposedContentOffset, CGPoint scrollingVelocity)
    {
        //Don't change anything
    }

}
```

Then in the SimpleCollectionViewController.cs, I add a UITextField for every cell, like this:

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell (UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var animalCell = (AnimalCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell (animalCellId, indexPath);

        var animal = animals [indexPath.Row];

        animalCell.Image = animal.Image;

        animalCell.AddSubview (new UITextField (new CGRect (0, 0, 100, 30)){ BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red });

        return animalCell;
    }
```

And still in SimpleCollectionViewController.cs, I add some code in ViewDidload method and add two method to handle the keyboard display event, like this:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        CollectionView.RegisterClassForCell (typeof(AnimalCell), animalCellId);
        CollectionView.RegisterClassForSupplementaryView (typeof(Header), UICollectionElementKindSection.Header, headerId);

        UIMenuController.SharedMenuController.MenuItems = new UIMenuItem[] {
            new UIMenuItem ("Custom", new Selector ("custom"))
        };

        this.View.AddGestureRecognizer(new UITapGestureRecognizer(()=>{
            this.View.EndEditing(true);
        }));

        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this,new ObjCRuntime.Selector("onKeyboardWillShowNotification:"),UIKeyboard.WillShowNotification,null);
        NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this,new ObjCRuntime.Selector("onKeyboardWillHideNotification:"),UIKeyboard.WillHideNotification,null);

    }

    [Export("onKeyboardWillShowNotification:")]
    private void OnKeyboardWillShowNotification(NSNotification notification)
    {
        LineLayout.FlagForLayout = false;
        NSDictionary userInfo = notification.UserInfo;
        CGSize keyboardSize = ((NSValue)userInfo[UIKeyboard.FrameBeginUserInfoKey]).RectangleFValue.Size;

        CGRect oldRect = CollectionView.Frame;
        CGRect aRect = new CGRect(oldRect.X, oldRect.Y - keyboardSize.Height, oldRect.Width,
            oldRect.Height);
        this.CollectionView.Frame = aRect;
    }

    [Export("onKeyboardWillHideNotification:")]
    private void OnKeyboardWillHideNotification(NSNotification notification)
    {
        LineLayout.FlagForLayout = true;
        this.CollectionView.Frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
    }
```

Now LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect will be invoked when keyboard show, hope it can solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Alanc! Yeah, I am using the Xamarin Sample. It was very helpful for what I needed. I like the suggestion of moving the view instead of resizing. I've tried the code you posted but it seems to still be calling LayoutAttributesForElementsInRect. Do you know how I can stop this getting called?

Comment: Wow, you totally revamped this. I'm going to try it as soon as I get a chance. Thank you, @Alanc-Liu